# data.table R fwrite bug on Red Hat Linux

Tags: r, data.table

I have been using data.table (v1.10) and noticed a bug when using fwrite. Some background.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
```

Have multi-core machine.

> #### Generate some data

```
#Generate some data
rows = 2500000
set.seed(Sys.time())
DF <- data.frame(index = 1:rows,
             catsA = sample((letters[1:10]),rows,replace=T),
             catsB = sample((letters[1:10]),rows,replace=T),
             catsC = sample((letters[1:10]),rows,replace=T),
             catsD = sample((letters[1:10]),rows,replace=T),
             catsE = sample((letters[1:10]),rows,replace=T),
             valueA = round(rnorm(rows),3),
             valueB = rpois(rows, lambda = 4))

#Convert to data.table
DT <- data.table(DF) 
#Create a new column
DT <- DT[,valueNew := valueA*valueB]

#Write
write.csv(DT,file="DT_write_csv.csv",row.names=F)
fwrite(DT, file = "DT_fwrite.csv",row.names=F)
```

> #### Read back in and join

```
#Read back in and join
DT_csv <- fread("DT_write_csv.csv")
DT_fwrite <- fread("DT_fwrite.csv")

setkey(DT_csv,"index")
setkey(DT_fwrite,"index")
join_DT <- DT_csv[DT_fwrite]
```

> #### Compare

```
nrow(join_DT[valueNew != i.valueNew])
[1] 1
join_DT[valueNew != i.valueNew,.(index,valueNew,i.valueNew)]
   index valueNew i.valueNew
1: 67097    2.855       5.71
DT[index==67097,.(valueNew)]
   valueNew
1:    2.855
```

From the **Compare** the original DT has the a that fwrite corrupts. Sometimes it is more than one row and in a real-life example propagated across many columns.

Am I doing something wrong with the fwrite?

Comment: Your comparison of index values would be more useful if your data were reproducible. Before making random data, use `set.seed(some_number)`.

Comment: Not comparing index values?

Comment: I get that `identical(DT_csv, DT_fwrite)` returns TRUE.

Comment: @imo Increase the number of rows to 2.5 million and check

Comment: You don't want to use `set.seed(Sys.time())` we don't know your value of `Sys.time()` and so can't reproduce your data set. Instead use some fixed integer. My favorite is 1234, but opinions vary.

Comment: @imo - set.seed is not the issue here.

Comment: `identical` returned TRUE for me using seed 1234 and sample size of 2.5 million.

Comment: @imo what's your sessionInfo()

Comment: R 3.2.5 microsoft, `data.table` 1.10.0.

Comment: @imo - looks like it is not reproduced on my MS machine either only Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a bug in `fwrite`. Fixed in dev last week and I'll try and get it to CRAN soon. Please check [**NEWS**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) link at the top of homepage, bug fix item 3 :

> `fwrite()` could write floating point values incorrectly, [#1968](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1968). A
>   thread-local variable was incorrectly thread-global. This variable's
>   usage lifetime is only a few clock cycles so it needed large data and
>   many threads for several threads to overlap their usage of it and
>   cause the problem. Many thanks to @mgahan and @jmosser for finding and
>   reporting.

Please try from dev by typing the command [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). I know that dev is currently failing Travis (an unrelated reason), which is why the installation command has been setup to install the *last-passing* commit from dev and therefore should be ok.